# How to fix Ambiguous constructor error in Netbeans?

Tags: java, android, netbeans

I am seeing a compile time error as follow

```
reference to BiometrucPrompt is ambiguous both constructor 
BiometricPrompt(FragmentActivity,Executor,AuthenticationCallback) in BiometricPrompt and constructor BiometricPrompt(Fragment,Executor,AuthenticationCallback) in BiometricPrompt match
```

and **BiometricPrompt is a Android/system generated class**

I am creating the object of `BiometricPrompt` as follow, you can see I am type casting the `mActivity` to `(FragmentActivity)`.

```
new BiomtericPrompt((FragmentActivity) mActivity, mExecutor, new BiometricPrompt.AuthenticationCallcack(){
....

})
```

The above code works fine in AndroidStudio but is giving error in NetBeans IDE 8.2.

Answer (score 0):

You cast the attribute "mActivity" to "FragmentAiviy", not "FragmentActivity". Or was that just a spelling mistake?

EDIT: Yes it was

Comment: yes that was a typo, but in the code I am casting it correctly

Comment: what type is mActivity of?

Comment: its android.app.Activity type which I am typecasting into android.support.v4.app.FragmenActivity

Comment: Mhm, all I found was this (don't know android well): https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment
It seems like this could be a framework issue?